# How do I implement this convex problem in CVXPY?

Tags: python, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, cvxpy

I am looking to implement the following optimization problem in CVXPY.

$$ \max _{x_t} x_t' \mu - \frac{\gamma}{2} x'_t \Sigma x_t - x'_t\Lambda \Delta x_t $$

where $\Delta x_t := x_t - x_{t-1}$ and $\Sigma$ and $\Lambda$ are positive definite symmetric matrices.

Here is my attempt:

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

N = 2
gamma = 0.01
xprev = [0.5, 0.5]
mu = [0.01, 0.01]
Sigma = np.diag([0.1 ** 2] * 2)
Lambda = Sigma * 0.01
x = cp.Variable(N)
obj_terms = []
constraints = []
xdiff = x - xprev

term1 = cp.sum(cp.multiply(mu, x))
term2 = gamma * 0.5 * cp.quad_form(x, Sigma)
term3 = x.T @ Lambda @ xdiff

term = (term1 - term2 - term3)
obj_terms.append(term)
objective = cp.Maximize(cp.sum(obj_terms))  
problem = cp.Problem(objective)
problem.solve()
x_value = x.value  
print(x_value)
```

However, this implementation always results in a DCP error. I believe this problem is a convex one. The problem child is the implementation `x.T @ Lambda @ xtdiff`. Can someone please help me figure out how to implement the term $x'_t\Lambda \Delta x_t$ in CVXPY?

Comment: How did you establish this is convex? I don't think it is. (Last term is spoiling things).

Comment: Please include the DCP error message

Comment: Where does this QP come from?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen It is convex given that $\Gamma$ and $\Lambda$ are symmetric matrices (see updated problem statement). One can establish by taking the derivative twice.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Here is the error. 
cvxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically: The objective is not DCP.

Comment: @Lydia Please provide such information in the question itself

Comment: Erwin is correct. You have not proved the problem is convex. Symmetry of the two matrices does not imply convexity.

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK Ok, sorry I meant positive definite symmetric matrices. I have also updated the question.

Comment: $x'\Lambda y$ is non convex. Reformulate as $x'\Lambda x -x' \Lambda p$ with $p=x_{t-1}$ being constant.